# Tensorflow Object Detection API training issues

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using Paperspace to train but I am running in to some issues that I haven't seen before. I have used the same machine before without any issues. The training simply just don't seem to start. I have reduced the batch size to 10 ( default 24 ).

Has anybody else had this problem?

This is the output I get when I run train.py within models/research/object_detection and it has been going for roughly an hour.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/paperspace/Documents/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py:210: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Summary name /clone_loss is illegal; using clone_loss instead.
2017-11-27 12:08:46.994554: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2
2017-11-27 12:08:47.109823: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:892] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-11-27 12:08:47.110204: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Quadro P4000 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.48
pciBusID: 0000:00:05.0
totalMemory: 7.92GiB freeMemory: 7.60GiB
2017-11-27 12:08:47.110230: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: Quadro P4000, pci bus id: 0000:00:05.0, compute capability: 6.1)
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't generated tf record file, check it in research folder generatetf.record  file for train and test file is their or not. 
If it is not their generate it first then delete all files except your model(faster_rcnn) and label.pbtxt files from training folder and then start training!